# Remove table separator in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want my table to have the same line width but every 4th rows, there is a thick line between two rows. For example between row number 4 and 5. How can I remove that? Also there is a thick vertical line next to the third column. I want to remove that too.
Thanks.

[image: Table]

```java
JTable table = new JTable(data, AuctionRequestData.getColumnNames());
table.setRowHeight(25);

TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(120);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

if (data.length <= 13) {
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scrollPane.getPreferredSize().width, data.length*25+23));
} else {
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scrollPane.getPreferredSize().width, 348));
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to know for sure but it could be an implementation of `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer` or an extension of something that implements it.

Comment: This could be a scaling issue.  What DPI is your OS using?

Comment: `scrollPane.setPreferredSize` is a bad idea.  If you really want to control this, explore the `Scrollable` `interface`, which `JTable` implements

Comment: [mcve] please..